# Cocoa pods installation issue for Worldpay

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, worldpay

I am trying install https://github.com/Worldpay/worldpay-lib-ios. Here I need to install `AFNetworking` using `cocoapods`. My Podfile is

```
target 'testWorldpayLibrary' do
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
end
```

On hitting `pod install` command, I am getting error.

````
### Error

```
TypeError - Unable to convert Ruby value `"AFNetworking"' into a CFTypeRef.
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:383:in `RubyValueToCFTypeRef'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:402:in `block in RubyHashToCFDictionary'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:400:in `each'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:400:in `RubyHashToCFDictionary'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:372:in `RubyValueToCFTypeRef'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:402:in `block in RubyHashToCFDictionary'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:400:in `each'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:400:in `RubyHashToCFDictionary'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:372:in `RubyValueToCFTypeRef'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:402:in `block in RubyHashToCFDictionary'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:400:in `each'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi/core_foundation.rb:400:in `RubyHashToCFDictionary'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi.rb:159:in `ruby_hash_write_devtoolscore'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi.rb:149:in `ruby_hash_write_xcode'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist/ffi.rb:72:in `write_to_path'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:46:in `write_to_path'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/xcodeproj-1.3.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:333:in `save'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:696:in `block in write_pod_project'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:141:in `message'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:688:in `write_pod_project'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:173:in `block in generate_pods_project'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:167:in `generate_pods_project'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:119:in `install!'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/sujit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Unable+to+convert+Ruby+value+%60%22AFNetworking%22%27+into+a+CFTypeRef.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
````

Can anyone point out what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgrade your ruby version to 2.3.0, the issue must be resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open Your Terminal

```
1.First time install Pod in your mac run this command<sudo gem install cocoapods>
2.cd <your project>
3.pod install
4.go to your project in your project open pod file add<pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'>
5.Again run the <pod install> command in terminal.
```

Answer (score 0):

First deintegrate pod from your project and than in your pod file add this,

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, ‘7.0’

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Its working perfect for me. I tried to install in my system and its worked.